# How to create a database connection object using a File object in Java

Tags: java, database

I am trying to create a database connection object in Java, wherein I wish to use the File object that I have in memory.
I am a bit reluctant to first write the file (that I have in memory) to disk and then read again from the disk to create a database connection w.r.t. where I have stored the file.

Is it possible to do so in Java? Can someone please guide me..

**Update 1 based on the comment**: I am reluctant to write to the disk and then read again as I find it un-necessary. I have a huge dump of files which are received over the network. If I keep writing them to the disk and then reading from it, I am (the processor) is essentially wasting a lot of time for the data to be written to the disk, just to be read right after the write is done. Reads and Writes to and from the disk are expensive, and if I have the data in memory, why do you think is it "*Vague*" for me to look for an ability to use it right away, rather than to first write, read and then load it back into memory?

**Update 2** - Ok, so I guess, rather than confusing more people I will elaborate a bit more on the situation. I am receiving the file over the network - so I have an array of bytes.

*Now first thing* - can I create an im-memory java.io.File object using that data (without having to write the contents to the disk)? If so, then the 2nd step would be my try to use that in memory File object (which is created using the bytes received over the network) - its a database file I know for sure, so would like to create a connection so that I can query.

Comment: Your question is too vague to give a meaningful, useful answer to. Why are you reluctant? Why do you want to write to a file and read it again? What data are you going to write and read? What does that have to do with a database connection?

Comment: What kind of database are you talking about here?

Comment: And what kind of "File object", for that matter.  A `java.io.File` is just a representation of the path to a disk file, not the file's contents.

Answer (score 1):

> can I create an im-memory java.io.File object using that data (without having to write the contents to the disk)?

No.  The `java.io.File` class is a cross-platform abstraction for *paths* (i.e. the locations of files on disk), it has no concern for the *data* contained in the file - indeed one of the common uses for `File` objects is to check whether a particular path refers to an existing file, a directory, or does not exist at all.

Whether you can make use of the data you hold in a `byte[]` without writing it to disk is something nobody can answer without knowing exactly which "database" system you're using, as the answer depends entirely on what the underlying library supports.